# Set icon for Task in Jump List (Windows)

Tags: icons, electron, jump-list

I am trying to set up a icon in the Tasks section of the [Jump List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/taskbar-extensions#tasks) for my Electron app. I already successfully set up a icon in the task bar. But I also want to set up my icon in the Tasks section of the Jump List. How can I do that?

I already tried to use the [app.setUserTask()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetusertaskstasks-windows) method and tried to set up a icon in my JSON file. The icon in the task bar and the icon in the its self is working. I also tried using .ico and .png.

The description and the title are working so I guess that I am doing something wrong with the path or something similar. The ico and png image are in the same directory as my main.js (for Electron).

```
app.setUserTasks([
    {
      program: process.execPath,
      arguments: '--new-window',
      iconPath: path.join(__dirname,"icon.ico").execPath,
      iconIndex: 1,
      title: 'myApp',
      description: 'myApp'
    }
  ])
```

Comment: It looks like you mixed up two things in the `iconPath`: per https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/task, you can use `iconPath: process.execPath` to display the application icon or use an absolute path: `iconPath: path.join(__dirname,"icon.ico")` (without `.execPath`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it looks like you mixed up two things in your `iconPath`. According to the [Electron docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/structures/task), you can use `process.execPath` to refer to the application executable or use any other absolute path. Since `path.join` returns a string, it won't have the `execPath` property. Secondly, I changed the `iconIndex` to 0.

**The following was tested on Windows 7 and Electron 4.1.4:**

It appears that PNG files do not work at all – you'll need to use ICO files for the Jump List. Furthermore, the icon cannot be taken from the `asar`. This means you need an ICO directly in the filesystem and you need to provide an absolute path to it.

Complete code sample:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const os = require('os')

let my_path

my_path = "C:\\icon.png"                                // doesn't work
my_path = "C:\\icon.ico"                                // works
my_path = process.execPath                              // works (uses application icon)
my_path = path.join(__dirname, "icon.png")              // doesn't work, translates to C:\path\to\app\resources\app.asar\icon.png
my_path = path.join(__dirname, "icon.ico")              // doesn't work, translates to C:\path\to\app\resources\app.asar\icon.ico
my_path = path.join(app.getAppPath(), "icon.ico")       // doesn't work, translates to C:\path\to\app\resources\app.asar\icon.ico
my_path = path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "icon.ico")  // works if icon.ico is in the same directory
                                                        // as the exe "packaged" by electron-packager, assuming icon.ico is copied in


if (os.platform() == "win32") {
    app.setUserTasks([{
        program: process.execPath,
        arguments: '--new-window',
        iconPath: my_path,
        iconIndex: 0,
        title: 'My App',
        description: 'Description of myApp'
    }])
}

let mainWindow

app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null
        app.quit()
    })
})
```

Here, `doesn't work` means a default icon is shown by Windows. I made sure that `icon.png` and `icon.ico` were in the `app.asar`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. icon is changed in the taskmanager, taskbar and the app its self
I used this [topic](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier/issues/487)

I made sure that the .exe and my img are in same folder. All of my icons are now changed except from the .exe its self.

Comment: Couldn't you edit your first answer to this question to make it more complete? Ideally, there'd be an answer that fully solves the original problem. Furthermore, it would help a lot if you added the code that you ended up using.